# How are co-ordinates calculated in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I've been trying to get the following code to display a rectangle at the bottom of an iPhone simulator in landscape mode:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 10)

let myRect = SKShapeNode(rectOf: size)
myRect.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:self.frame.maxY - 50)
myRect.strokeColor = SKColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
myRect.lineWidth = 4

myRect.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)

myRect.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
myRect.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

The result of this is that the rectangle is not drawn inside the visible screen; I then inserted this debug statement:

```
print(self.frame.minY, self.frame.maxY, self.frame.minX, self.frame.maxX, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
```

Which outputs this:

```
-667.0 667.0 -375.0 375.0 750.0 1334.0
```

Further, when I changed the co-ordinates to `y:100` I noticed the shape move up - not down.  So, my question is: when the phone is in landscape mode, do I need to manually translate the X & Y co-ordinates and, do I need to know which way it has been rotated so that I can tell up from down?

Comment: Something strange going here... You self.frame is double size of the screen and has origins in -667.0 -375... Fix this and your code must work fine.

Comment: @Shebuka that is what his scene size is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand the difference between `Scene` and `Screen`.  These are 2 independent constructs in iPhone development.

When creating a SpriteKit game in XCode 11 (Others may vary), the default Scene size is 750x1334. This is the "Standard" size now.

What this means is on a standard size iPhone device, you will get pixel perfect graphics,  everything else will either scale or resize the scene to fit the screen.

There are 4 modes to accomplish this, .aspectFill, .aspectFit, .fill, .resize and are set via scaleMode.  I am not going to go into all of these, you can look it up, but the default in the template is .aspectFill.

What .aspectFill means is preserve the aspect ratio and scale the image until all edges are covered, leaving no black bars.  This means cropping will happen if your scene does not meet the aspect ratio of your screen.

Now when dealing with orientation,  you need to find some way to handle this, because the scene will still stay the same size, and be forced to scale or resize.

So what is happening, is your scene is in an aspect ratio of 9:16, but your screen is in an aspect ratio of 16:9.  this means it is going to scale your scene to a factor of 16:28.44~ to make sure that all screen edges are covered.  This means 68% (19.44~/28.44~) of your scene is now getting cropped to fit the scene.

To remedy this, you have a few choices.

1) You can support only 1 orientation, and set the scene size to properly fit it.

2) You can design your scene in a square, and handle cropping on both sides.

3) You can design multiple scenes to handle aspect ratio

4) You can manually keep changing the size and work on a percentage based positioning.

Of these choices,  I recommend either doing the 1 or 2

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'd be very happy to go with (1), as I'm the game that I'm working on is always going to be landscape anyway; however, just to clarify what you're saying, I can use absolute co-ordinates (for example:         player.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:-150)) and whatever the screen size or aspect ration happens to be, it will be adjusted accordingly?

Comment: no, use absolute of scene size, not screen size, and it will scale.  To do 1), go into your SKS file and swap the scene width and height.  Also go into your project settings and turn off portrait